Sequelize - Avoid named binding parameters when using sequelize.fn
I am using Sequelize 6.21.3 to access a MariaDB 10.8 database. In that database i have a Users table that contains a password column which is encoded with the SQL function ENCODE.
Now I'd like to update a user's password via sequelize. I do the following:
user.update({
    password: sequelize.fn(
        "encode",
        password,
        "ENCODE_PASSWORD"
    )
});

However if the password contains a $ sign (like in "123$foo"), the update query results in an error:
Named bind parameter "$foo" has no value in the given object.

I understand that sequelize tries to fill the value of the $foo parameter, however $foo is not supposed to be a parameter, it is just a literal string.
How do I avoid this behavior?

DO NOT ENCRYPT/ENCODE THE USER'S PASSWORD!
You need to be hashing the password with a salt before storing it in the database. That way when your database is compromised, which history has shown no matter who you are it will happen, those that stole the data can't use that data to try and log into other sites that the user's may have re-used their password on.
See bcrypt for more information.
With that said it looks like this was a known issue as there was a thread on their Github repo about it.
